# ringbuffer for ByteArrayOutputStream in java

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream

i am looking for something like ByteArrayOutputStream but with limited size. If size is exceeded older data should be overwritten. That is as far as i understand a ringbuffer. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want it to extend OutputStream?

Comment: may be? i just want an implementation where memory usage is restricted? In ByteArrayOutputStream the byte array grows without limit as far as i understand.

Answer (score 4):

There's not really much to it. You could do it yourself. Here is a start:

```
class ByteArrayRingBuffer extends OutputStream {

    byte[] data;
    int capacity, pos = 0;
    boolean filled = false;

    public ByteArrayRingBuffer(int capacity) {
        data = new byte[capacity];
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int b) {
        if (pos == capacity) {
            filled = true;
            pos = 0;
        }
        data[pos++] = (byte) b;
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray() {
        if (!filled)
            return Arrays.copyOf(data, pos);
        byte[] ret = new byte[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(data, pos, ret, 0, capacity - pos);
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, ret, capacity - pos, pos);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

(You may want to override `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` if you need the efficiency.)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed. I just wondered if i am the only one how is in need for such a thing? Doesn't seem to exotic to me.

Comment: Have you searched for "java ringbuffer" on google? There are tons of implementations.